# Split array, average sub-arrays, return new array of averages?

Tags: ruby

Say that I have the array `[35, 20, 15, 22, 18, 40, 16, 40]`. 8 digits.

What I want is a 4 digit array where each digit is the result of averaging two digits in the first array.

So it'd be `[(average of 35 and 20), (average of 15 and 22), (average of 18 and 40), (average of 16 and 40)]`.

I strongly suspected that there's some clever way to do this using `each_slice`, `map`, or `inject`, but can't quite guess at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite right:

```
[35, 20, 15, 22, 18, 40, 16, 40]
  .each_slice(2)
  .map {|pair| pair.inject(:+) / pair.length.to_f }
```

`each_slice(2)` produces slices of up to 2 elements long, which you can then sum and divide by the length of the slice.

Comment: Being slightly too clever here. Just use `.each_slice(2).map { |a,b| (a + b) / 2.0 }`

Comment: @meagar that will produce incorrect results in the case that the input array has an odd number of elements.

Comment: Yes, I just saw your update. However, an odd number of inputs should be considered an error condition, so...

Comment: If odd numbers of elements were permitted, the block @meagar suggested could be modified slightly: `{ |a,b| (a + b.to_i)/(b ? 2.0 : 1.0) }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Now it's too complex in the other direction, and I would prefer the `pair.inject`/`par.length` approach :p

Comment: Also note that, if this is part of a Rails application, you can use `[....].each_slice(2).map(&:average)` and be done with it

Comment: @Meagar, just sayin', not pushin'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array contains an even number of elements, which I believe is intended, here's a FORTRAN IV approach:

```
arr = [35, 20, 15, 22, 18, 40, 16, 40]

(0...arr.size).step(2).map { |i| (arr[i]+arr[i+1])/2.0 }
  #=> [27.5, 18.5, 29.0, 28.0]
```

and another inspired by FORTH+:

```
def ex(op, v0, v1)
  v1.send op, v0
end

a = arr.dup
stack = []
while a.any?
  stack.unshift(a.pop)
  stack.unshift(a.pop)
  stack.unshift(:+)
  stack.unshift(ex(stack.shift, stack.shift, stack.shift))
  stack.unshift(2.0)
  stack.unshift(:/)
  stack.unshift(ex(stack.shift, stack.shift, stack.shift))
end
stack
  #=> [27.5, 18.5, 29.0, 28.0]
```

Hmmm. Why did I think FORTH+<sup>1</sup> was so cool? Leo Brodie's book *[Starting Forth](http://www.forth.com/starting-forth/)* probably had a lot to do with it.

<sup>1 Historical note: the Lotus 1-2-3 clone, [VP-Planner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperback_Software_International), was written in FORTH by a friend, Kent Brothers.</sup>